# Быстро узнать подотрезок в дереве отрезков

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Узнал что такео дерево отрезков и как с ним работать [вот тут](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree#14). В этой статье есть много полезных методов, но нету такого, который вроде кажется фундаментальным, что-то вроде

```
vector<int> get_sub(int v, int tl, int tr, l, r) {
    //Что-то там
    //Вернуть вектор, в котором значения массива с l по r
}
```

Я конечно понимаю, что можно написать что-то типа

```
vector<int> get_sub(int l, int r) {
    vector<int> res;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; ++i) {
        res.push_back(get(1, 0, n - 1, i)) //get - Метод из статьи (возвращает элемент на позиции i)
    }

    return res
```

Но это очень долго...

Есть ли где-нибудь реализация чего-нибудь такого, что бы быстро возвращало подотрезок массива (желательно на C++, но в принципе любой язык подойдет)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, я никогда не встречал таких задач, где нужно вернуть сам отрезок. Я встречал задачи, где нужно вернуть его в отсортированном виде. Ведь тогда на подотрезке можно будет запустить бинарный поиск, или еще что-то придумать.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:25600000000000000000000000000000000")
#define qq cout << "!!" << endl;
#define ww cout << "??" << endl;
#define rr return 0;
#define nl cout << endl;
#define pb push_back
#define mk make_pair
#define sqr(a) ((a) * (a))
#define imp(a) fixed << setprecision(a)
#define x first
#define y second
#define acmSqrt(a) __asm__ ("fsqrt" : "+t" (a));

#define int ll

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef long double ld;
typedef pair<int, int> pp;
typedef pair<double, double> point;

vector<int> A;
vector<int> *tree;

int n;

inline void build(int k, int left, int right) {

    if(left == right) {
        tree[k] = { A[left] };
        return;
    }

    register int center = (left + right) / 2;

    build(k * 2, left, center);
    build(k * 2 + 1, center + 1, right);

    merge(tree[k * 2].begin(), tree[k * 2].end(),
          tree[k * 2 + 1].begin(), tree[k * 2 + 1].end(),
          back_inserter(tree[k]));
}

inline vector<int> query(int k, int left, int right, int l, int r) {

    if(l == left && r == right) {
        return tree[k];
    }

    register int center = (left + right) / 2;

    if(r <= center) {
        return query(k * 2, left, center, l, r);
    }

    if(l > center) {
        return query(k * 2 + 1, center + 1, right, l, r);
    }

    vector<int> a = query(k * 2, left, center, l, center);
    vector<int> b = query(k * 2 + 1, center + 1, right, center + 1, r);

    vector<int> c;

    merge(a.begin(), a.end(),
          b.begin(), b.end(),
          back_inserter(c));

    return c;
}

int l, r;

main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    srand(time(NULL));
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    cin >> n;

    A.resize(n);
    tree = new vector<int>[4 * n];

    for(register int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    build(1, 0, n - 1);

    while(cin >> l >> r) {
        vector<int> t = query(1, 0, n - 1, --l, --r);
        for(auto &a : t) {
            cout << a << " ";
        }
        nl;
    }
}
```

P.S. Прости за кучу лишнего кода, это мой шаблон.

Comment: А нету где-нибудь шаблона с прибавлением на отрезке и суммой на отрезке?

Comment: @Philippe, в том смысле, чтоб можно было и выводить отрезок, и делать обновление на отрезке, и искать сумму на отрезке?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно выводить отрезок, просто делать обновление на отрезке и взять сумму на отрезке

Comment: Честно говоря, про прибавление на отрезке не знаю. Знаю, что есть присвоение на отрезке (все элементы от l до r будут равны d) с суммой на отрезке.
Делается это с помощью "проталкивания" (push).
https://pastebin.com/hNXFdQsY

Вот пример задачи (с решением): https://site.ada.edu.az/~medv/acm/Docs%20e-olimp/Volume%2030/2939.htm